# How to split a string into letters

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, str-replace

I need to import a 2 line txt file and change every "e" in the file to "bob"
I know you start by the following but I am having a hard time of getting the words in the string into a string of letters so that I can use the .replace("e","bob") method.

The txt file is the following:

```
Hey Jim, how are you doing today?
I hope all is well with you.
```

My code is as follows:

```
text = open(input("Enter file name"), "r")
textline = text.readlines()

numline = 0

for line in textline:
    numline = numline + 1
    textword = line.split()
    lineletter = list(line)
    z = str(lineletter)
    q = z.replace('e', 'zw')

    print(lineletter)
    print(textword)
    print(z)
```

Where to go from here?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Why do you need `numline`?

Comment: "How to split a string into letters" is trivial: a string is already a sequence of characters, so you don't have to do anything. (If you'd rather have a different kind of sequence for some reason, like a `list`, you can just call `list(s)`.)

Comment: But why do you want to split it into a string of letters in the first place? The whole point of `replace` is that it works on a whole string at once, searching for `'e'`s to replace.

Comment: output would be "Hboby Jim, how arbob you doing today? /n I hopbob all is webob with you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to go for splitting just replacing would be enough.

```
with open("file", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.replace('e', 'bob'), end="")
```